# What is the meaning of this ANTLR3 log message?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

Antlr3 produces the following output to `System.out`, while doing everything else correctly:

```
line 0:0 null
line 0:0 null
line 0:0 null
...
```

What is it about?

ps. The problem is that during parsing time to time I through `RecognitionException()`. Looks like `null` is the result of this. Instead of `null` there should be some meaningful message, but [RecognitionException](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_recognition_exception.html) doesn't have such a constructor. What to do?

---

```
grammar Bar;
document: ( CHAR { Foo.validate($CHAR.text); } )+ EOF;
CHAR: 'a'..'z';
```

`Foo` class somewhere in the same package:

```
public class Foo {
  public static void validate(String txt) throws RecognitionException {
    if ("q".equals(txt)) {
      throw new RecognitionException();
    }
  }
}
```

Now a unit test:

```
public class BarTest {
  @Test public void testEverything() throws Exception {
    this.parse("abc"); // valid
    this.parse("abcq"); // invalid
  }
  private void parse(String txt) {
    CharStream input = new ANTLRStringStream(txt);
    BarLexer lexer = new BarLexer(input);
    TokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    BarParser parser = new BarParser(tokens);
    parser.document();
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
line 0:0 null
```

Comment: Well, it's rather obvious, isn't it? :-D (I sometimes find that antlr3's messages may be cryptic indeed)

Comment: Nah, not obvious at all.. Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: possibly empty lines in the grammar? Can you post what's generating the error?

Comment: It'd help if you posted the grammar and test input that produced this...

Comment: What is the meaning of this message? What ANTLR is trying to tell me? Where is NULL? I will try to post grammar now (it's quite big)...

Comment: @yegor, one can only guess: if you want to find out, you'll need to post the grammar and test input at the very least.

Comment: @yegor, I'm afraid that doesn't help much. For the 3rd time: could you post the grammar and input that causes this? If it's too large, please make it shorter but still produces the error. My guess is that although the message is not descriptive at all, the error still lies in your grammar. But I can only guess (just as anyone else). FYI: the -1 is from me since I find the question lacking too much details. I'll gladly remove it if you improve it though.

Comment: @Bart sorry, I didn't mean to be non-informative. I already updated the question with as much details as possible. As you see, it's a testing example, but it is very close to what I have in my real-life case. Please let me know what do you think. Not a problem with "-1", I think I deserve it :)

Comment: Aah, you throw the exception yourself! Let me look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RecognitionException` is supposed to be thrown by the parser itself. Such exceptions have all kind of information that is updated while the parser goes through the token stream (line number, index, current token, etc.). So, you shouldn't throw them yourself.

Have a look at these two Wiki articles that handles error reporting and recovery:

- [Error reporting and recovery](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Error+reporting+and+recovery)
- [Custom Syntax Error Recovery](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Custom+Syntax+Error+Recovery)

Comment: thanks for the links, I reviewed them carefully, but failed to understand what type of exception I should throw.. Could you please give an example suitable for my case?

Comment: @yegor256, why not simply throw a RuntimeException (or something else from Java's standard API)?